# Codeigniter how to create CMS editor for css / js / php like wordpress editor

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter 3x and I want to create some part of CMS in my Codeigniter project like to read/load content file from `CSS/JS/ header_view.php`,`footer_view.php` and save it so it override that file like wordpress Editor do.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here the steps:

1. Show the list of files to the user
2. Allow them to click on a file
3. Load that file content and print it in a view or in a WYSIWYG editor
4. When they save get the whole content and override the old one.

To show the list of file just use:

```
$dir = 'path/to/your/css/files'
$files = glob($dir.'*');
```

Now in your view, for each file just create a link to your controller method that accepts the file name, for example:

```
foreach($files as $file){
    <li><a href="path/to/your/controller/method/".$file>$file</a></li>
}
```

In this way you have the link to the file, so you can recreate the full path that you should know ( if you want you can extend a link with some `data-` attribute to make it easier ).

Now you are in the controller method, so just load the file content and send it to the view:

```
$file_name = ''; // the one you get from the method link
$content = read_file($file_name);
// load the view and the editor
```

Now allow the user to make all the changes he/she wants and then save the data:

```
$file_name = ""; // Name of the file, you can get it from the url, or adding as input in the form
$file_content = html_entity_decode($this->input->post('file_content'));
write_file($file_name , $file_content)
```

Always make sure to re-create the full path to the file.

Comment: hi des `$dir = 'path/to/your/css/files'; ` do i need use base_url here ?